# Milnor-Wolf result on growth of solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, growth-rate

The Milnor-Wolf theorem says that any solvable group has either polynomial or exponential growth. I wonder about the existence of alternative proofs of this fact. I have an impression that the original proof is more brutal and less ideological. If you have a citation or a suggestion of an alternative proof, please post.

Comment: Would you say something about what the original proof is? the only proof I have in mind consists in proving 1) if $G$ is f.g. virtually nilpotent, then it has polynomial growth 2) if $G$ is f.g. solvable and not virtually nilpotent, then it has a free subsemigroup. There are probably several proofs of (2).

Comment: I could check Milnor's paper but not Wolf's. Milnor (J. Diff Geom. 2, p447-449, 1968) checks that if $G$ is f.g. solvable but not polycyclic then it has exponential growth. His proof actually shows it contains a free subsemigroup (see the reasoning by contradiction in his Lemma 1), although he doesn't say it.

Comment: Yes, Yves, this is exactly how it goes. What are the alternative proofs of 2?

Comment: There's one proof of 2 using the fact, due to Groves (1978), that a non-vn f.g. solvable group has a homomorphism into $K^*\ltimes K$ with non-vn image for some non-discrete locally compact field $K$, and using this we can play ping-pong on the tree/hyperbolic 2/3-space, without distinction between the polycyclic and non-polycyclic case.

Comment: But the original proof has the advantage to generalize to elementary amenable groups (Chou, 1980).

Comment: Certain special classes of solvable groups are covered by the simple argument in the appendix to Gromov's paper on groups of polynomial growth by Tits. For example, the argument applies to a lattice in a 3-dimensional solvable Lie group. The point is that a finitely generated abelian-by-cyclic group has exponential growth if the cyclic group acts on the abelian subgroup with an eigenvalue $>1$ in absolute value. Maybe one can show that a non-vn solvable group contains such a subgroup or else contains a solvable Baumslag-Solitar subgroup?

Comment: I am also interested in generalization of Chou to the class of elementary amenable groups. It would wonderful if this can be explained in a better form. All books that discuss amenability deliberately avoid these proofs, since it is too technical.

Comment: Osin actually improved Chou's result, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404075, and indeed had to go into the technicalities. He proves uniform exponential growth. Actually there are a few other improvements that are known for non-vn f.g. solvable groups, but not known for elementary amenable groups, such as: - the existence of a QI-embedded free subsemigroup on 2 generators - exponential conjugacy growth.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a different proof of a sharper result by our own T. Tao:
http://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/milnor-wolf-theorem/